# Trying to build OMNI Notes: Cannot find resource android:attr/textAppearanceSmall

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently trying to build OMNI Notes. In the **styles.xml**, it refers to `android:attr/textAppearanceSmall`. But when I try to build it in Android Studio, it fails to build because this can't be found.

What do I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by replacing it by "Android:TextAppearance.Small"!

Hope I could help someone with that